# Adding a Meta to the wp_get_archives

Tags: wp-get-archives

I'm trying to add a meta to `wp_get_archives`

```
add_filter('getarchives_where','my_archives_filter');

function my_archives_filter($where_clause) {

    if(!is_user_logged_in()){
        return "WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'";
    }else{
        return $where_clause;
    }

}
```

I want to add the distinction of getting posts that have the meta `private_page='0'` when The user is not logged in, but I can't find how to put the meta distinction in the `return "WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'";`. The line before is what I tried, and it returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to include postmeta into query that you're using for archive pages in a kind of this way:

```
add_filter('getarchives_join', 'my_archives_join_filter');

function my_archives_join_filter($join) {
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        global $wpdb;
        return $join . "LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)";
    }
    return $join;
}
```

2) You need to include condition to select a post with specific metafield in this way:

```
add_filter('getarchives_where', 'my_archives_where_filter');

function my_archives_where_filter($where_clause) {
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        global $wpdb;
        $where_clause = "WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post' AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'";
        return $where_clause . "AND $wpdb->posts.meta_key = 'private_page' AND $wpdb->posts.meta_value = '0'";
    } 
     return $where_clause;
}
```

Code where not tested for your specific case. But the approach in general should be clear.

UPDATE: where curious enough to test an approach. All works ;)